# how to check UDP Connection

Tags: c++, udp, posix

Here I am checking UDP connection of IP address with specific port by using attached code. In my code if I give any IP and any port number it is getting connected successfully, the max range of port number is 5 digit but if I give more than 5 digit it will still get connection.
Major thing is on giving failure cases to check UDP Connection it passed that cases also.
failure cases i choosed:
1)not reachable IP
2)giving any port number

please help me to figure out what mistake i did in my code and what i can do in my code to check UDP connection is available for IP with specific port.My code attached below.

Thanks in Advance

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>



using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int sockfd,rv;  
        struct addrinfo *servinfo, *p,hints;
        struct sockaddr_in *h;
        string host ="172.30.36.150";
        int port=8997345;

        memset(&hints, 0, sizeof hints);

                struct sockaddr_in clientService;
                int serversockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP);

                if (serversockfd == -1) {
                        fprintf(stderr, "Error in socket %d\n", errno);
                }
                clientService.sin_family = AF_INET;
                rv = getaddrinfo( host.c_str() , NULL , &hints , &servinfo);

                string strhost = "";

                if(rv ==0){
                        p = servinfo;
                        h = (struct sockaddr_in *) p->ai_addr;
                        char chost[INET_ADDRSTRLEN];
                        strcpy(chost , inet_ntoa( h->sin_addr ) );
                        strhost.append(chost);
                        freeaddrinfo(servinfo);

                } 
                clientService.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(strhost.c_str());
                clientService.sin_port = htons((u_short)port);



                int res = connect(serversockfd, (struct sockaddr*) &clientService,
                                sizeof(clientService));


                close(serversockfd);



                if (res == -1) {
                        fprintf(stderr, "Error connecting socket %d\n", errno);

                }else{
                    cout<<"successfully connected"<<endl;
                }

}
```

Comment: Remember that UDP is *connectionless*. There *is* no established connection - it's basically fire-and-forget with no error checking (unless you build it yourself).

Comment: What is `sizeof(int)` on your system?

Comment: You *may* be interrested in [ENet](http://enet.bespin.org/).

Comment: @ Adder
sizeof(int) is 4, why you asked this?